Is every isometry invariant measure on Euclidean space equivalent to Hausdorff measure?
One of the properties of Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is invariance under isometry.
I wonder that if every isometry-invariant measure is similar to Hausdorff measure.
To be rigorous, let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$. Here, $\mu$ is nontrivial in the sense that there exists a Borel set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $0<\mu(E)<\infty$. We denote a Hausdorff measure $H^d$ of dimension $d$ using the notation of Wikipedia.
Then, here is my question:
If $\mu$ is a nontrivial Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is invariant under isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual metric, is there $r\in(0,\infty)$ and $d\in[0,\infty)$ such that $\mu=rH^d$?

This unanswered question on MO seems to be closely related. There the question observes that a slightly more general class of Hausdorff-type measures has this property.

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you for letting me know! I guess this kind of problem is open currently.

I found https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/82B5E841B3A74C06F05313B67AC8885D/S014338570000167Xa.pdf/div-class-title-finitely-additive-invariant-measures-on-euclidean-spaces-div.pdf interesting.
